# momentjs convert datetime to UTC from another timezone

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I'm having dates like the below:

**05/30/2014 11:21:37 AM**

My users will be entering in that data and having their own timezone. It could be anything like "US/Eastern", "US/Pacific-New", etc. I want to convert the time to UTC but i'm not able to. Is there a way to do so?

I'm using node and I tried momentJS and read the below:

http://momentjs.com/docs/

http://momentjs.com/guides/

[Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

How do I convert from a different timezone to UTC?

**Edit**

I have tried these:

```
moment().utc(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z')
moment.tz(dateString, "US/Eastern").format()
```

In the above example `dateString` is the string date. I want to set the timezone to "US/Eastern" and convert it to UTC.

Comment: If you're going to down vote please explain why. I have clearly tried many things for this.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
// your inputs
var input = "05/30/2014 11:21:37 AM"
var fmt   = "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A";  // must match the input
var zone  = "America/New_York";

// construct a moment object
var m = moment.tz(input, fmt, zone);

// convert it to utc
m.utc();

// format it for output
var s = m.format(fmt)  // result: "05/30/2014 3:21:37 PM"
```

Note that I used the same output format as input format - you could vary that if you like.

You can also do this all in one line if you prefer:

```
var s = moment.tz(input, fmt, zone).utc().format(fmt);
```

Additionally, note that I used the Area/Locality format (`America/New_York`), instead of the older `US/Eastern` style.  This should be prefered, as the US/* ones are just there for backwards compatibility purposes.

Also, `US/Pacific-New` should never be used.  It is now just the same as `US/Pacific`, which both just point to `America/Los_Angeles`.  For more on the history of this, [see the tzdb sources](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/pacificnew).

Comment: hi @Matt mon problem is that  I have not the input date in string format, but in UTC, and moment or any function can convert it to string, i get always convert to stringl like Wed Nov 01 2017 12:22:04 GMT+0100 (CET), any ideas?

Comment: @stackdave - I don't understand your comment. It appears to be unrelated to the question here.  Please ask in a new question with supporting details.

Comment: After two days of struggle. This solution worked for me.
Thank you so much @MattJohnson-Pint

Comment: TypeError: moment_1.default.tz is not a function
`const input = moment(req.query.created_at).format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A");`
`const clientDate = moment.tz(input, "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A", timezone).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A");`

Comment: What if I am getting input date from client, How can I know format than than.

Comment: @TirathSharma - if it's _arbitrary_ input, then you can't.  For example, if I give you `01/02/03`, that could be any of `DD/MM/YY`, `MM/DD/YY`, or `YY/MM/DD` format - there's no way to know from the data alone.

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37534798/4149861)'s answer; but using *moment-timezone* to convert date-time to UTC  (as ISO string):

```
var momentTz = require('moment-timezone');
var utcDate = momentTz.tz('2021-01-27 14:02:45', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", 'Asia/Kolkata').toISOString();
console.log(utcDate);

// output: '2021-01-27T08:32:45.000Z'
```

The api I was working with required date-time in UTC & in ISO format